# Laravel - how to use task scheduling by user not coder?

Tags: laravel, task, scheduling

I want to implement my project like this.
Users post forms decide when to run the task scheduling 
and add filter conditions to select data from database.
Can laravel5.1 achieve this target?

Comment: Of course anything can be achieved its just a question of how. My approach would probably to have the form post to a model which saves meta data about the tasks to run, and then there would basically be a scheduled task run every minute to check if there are any user-scheduled tasks that should be started and then to handle creating those tasks if need be. That would prob be my approach.. If you've got a more specific coding question then show what you have done and where you got stuck so we can help you move through it

Comment: This is already sort of what laravel does for you to enable writing scheduled tasks in your code rather than Cron jobs explicitly, it could be worth looking into hooking into that possibly for a more robust solution.

Comment: i am inspired ,thank you for your help ,i will try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that laraval queue is something that you need :)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues

Comment: Now I use a github project [Cron](https://github.com/liebig/cron), anyway thanks for your help.